# Adding Child element to XML

Tags: php, xml

I have XML of the form

```
$xml=<<<EOD
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CompleteSaleRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<RequesterCredentials>
<eBayAuthToken>AUTH_TOKEN_VALUE</eBayAuthToken>
</RequesterCredentials>
<ItemID>ItemIDVALUE</ItemID>
<TransactionID>TransactionIDVALUE</TransactionID>
<Shipped>1</Shipped>
<Paid>1</Paid>
  <Shipment>
    <ShipmentTrackingDetails>
   <ShipmentTrackingNumber>$trackingNo</ShipmentTrackingNumber>
      <ShippingCarrierUsed>UPS</ShippingCarrierUsed>
    </ShipmentTrackingDetails>
    <ShippedTime>2014-09-30 12:41:59.202303</ShippedTime>
    </Shipment>
<ErrorLanguage> string </ErrorLanguage>
EOD;
```

I want to append more ShipmentTrackingDetails portion using PHP, I need the resulting XML like this:

```
$xml=<<<EOD
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CompleteSaleRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<RequesterCredentials>
<eBayAuthToken>AUTH_TOKEN_VALUE</eBayAuthToken>
</RequesterCredentials>
<ItemID>ItemIDVALUE</ItemID>
<TransactionID>TransactionIDVALUE</TransactionID>
<Shipped>1</Shipped>
<Paid>1</Paid>
  <Shipment>
    <ShipmentTrackingDetails>
   <ShipmentTrackingNumber>$trackingNo</ShipmentTrackingNumber>
      <ShippingCarrierUsed>UPS</ShippingCarrierUsed>
    </ShipmentTrackingDetails>

 <ShipmentTrackingDetails>
   <ShipmentTrackingNumber>$trackingNo2</ShipmentTrackingNumber>
      <ShippingCarrierUsed>UPS</ShippingCarrierUsed>
    </ShipmentTrackingDetails>

 <ShipmentTrackingDetails>
   <ShipmentTrackingNumber>$trackingNo3</ShipmentTrackingNumber>
      <ShippingCarrierUsed>UPS</ShippingCarrierUsed>
    </ShipmentTrackingDetails>
    <ShippedTime>2014-09-30 12:41:59.202303</ShippedTime>
    </Shipment>
<ErrorLanguage> string </ErrorLanguage>
EOD;
```

PHP Source:

```
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml); 
$track = $sxe->addChild('ShipmentTrackingDetails'); 
$track->addChild("ShipmentTrackingNumber", "9876"); 
$track->addChild("ShippingCarrierUsed", "USPS");
```

I am not getting how to do this using php. 
Please help in getting this working.

Thanks!

Comment: Use [DOM](http://php.net/dom), in particular [appendChild()](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.appendchild.php)

Comment: Well that looks like valid php to me, whats actually wrong with using the code as is?

Comment: Please post the PHP code that you are using to try to alter your XML.

Comment: My PHP code is:                                              $sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml); 
$track= $sxe->addChild('ShipmentTrackingDetails'); 
$track->addChild("ShipmentTrackingNumber", "9876"); 
$track->addChild("ShippingCarrierUsed", "USPS"); 
        but the new  element is getting appended at the end of the  xml like: <ErrorLanguage> string </ErrorLanguage>
<ShipmentTrackingDetails><ShipmentTrackingNumber>9876</ShipmentTrackingNumber><ShippingCarrierUsed>USPS</ShippingCarrierUsed></ShipmentTrackingDetails></CompleteSaleRequest>
 I want it to be inside <Shipment></shipment>

Comment: @Developer: Edit that in your question, not inside a comment below. Those comments tend to not be very readable... .

Comment: Sorry for that. I got the answer. Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it,
The dynamic part would be:

```
 $sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);  
    $TrackingDetails = $sxe->Shipment->addChild('ShipmentTrackingDetails'); 
    $TrackingDetails->addChild("ShipmentTrackingNumber", $trackingMore); 
    $TrackingDetails->addChild("ShippingCarrierUsed", "UPS"); 
    $sxe->asXML("tracking.xml");
    $xml1 = $sxe->saveXML();
```

Where $xml is the original xml to which we want to add new child.